# play/pause button on media player

Tags: android

I used the media player example on [this](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer) , I create a navigation drawer and showed the play/pause button there. I got that working , I got one problem, For example I clicked the play button and it will show a notif loading and after loading it will update the notif to playing and then the play button will change into pause button. If i click the service notif I want the state of the button to show like it should be showing the pause coz the media player is playing, but instead it shows the play button.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

edit: play/pause code:

```
public void onClick(View target) {
// Send the correct intent to the MusicService, according to the button that was clicked
    switch (target.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_button:
            startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY));
            mPlayButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
            mPauseButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.pause_button:
            startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PAUSE));
            // pause music here
            mPauseButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
            mPlayButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
            break;


    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code that updates your play/pause button.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have updated my question with play/pause code for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose clicking your notification restarts your activity and recreates the "play" button. You need to add code that checks if the music is playing when activity gets started and updates your buttons accordingly.